# How to write a function for barchart in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using  bar-charts for my Exploratory data analysis.I have generated around 18 bar-charts in the entire analysis with similar peace of code.So i don't want to write the same code all the time for every bar-chart. the code i have used for the bar-chart is

```
y = textranges_freq['smstext']
xlabels = textranges_freq['buckets']
bar_width = 0.50
x = np.arange(len(y))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(x, y, width=bar_width)
ax.set_xticks(x+(bar_width/2.0))
ax.set_xticklabels(xlabels)
ax.set_title('Avg text Frequency by range')
ax.set_xlabel('buckets')
ax.set_ylabel('Avg text messages')
plt.show()
```

I have used the same code around 18 times in my analysis because i need to
change y,xlabels,title,ax.set_title,ax.set_xlabel,ax.set_ylabel.
so how can i write the function for this to use further.
In the above code textranges_freq is my dataframe and smstext,buckets are my variables.
please help me on this. I am new to python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap the whole thing in a function:

```
y = textranges_freq['smstext']
xlabels = textranges_freq['buckets']
def makebar(y, xlabels, xlabel, ylabel, title):
    bar_width = 0.50
    x = np.arange(len(y))
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.bar(x, y, width=bar_width)
    ax.set_xticks(x+(bar_width/2.0))
    ax.set_xticklabels(xlabels)
    ax.set_title(title)
    ax.set_xlabel(xlabel)
    ax.set_ylabel(ylabel)
    plt.show()
```

However, an even easier approach would be to plot from the DataFrame directly:

```
ax = textranges_freq.plot(x='buckets',y='smstext',kind='bar',title='Avg text Frequency by range', width=0.5, legend=False)
ax.set_xlabel('buckets')
ax.set_ylabel('Avg text messages')
plt.show()
```

This isn't much more work than just calling the function directly, but if you really wanted you could wrap it in a function, too:

```
def df_bar(df, xcol, ycol, xlabel=None, ylabel=None, title=None):
    if xlabel is None:
        xlabel = xcol
    if ylabel is None:
        ylabel = xcol    
    ax = textranges_freq.plot(x=xcol,y=ycol,kind='bar',title=title, width=0.5, legend=False)
    ax.set_xlabel(xlabel)
    ax.set_ylabel(ylabel)
    plt.show()
```

This also has the advantage that if the x or y label is the same as the column name (as is the case for the xlabel in the example), you can just skip the corresponding label and it will use the column name instead.  You also can leave the title blank.

Answer (score 0):

I would structure your data into lists.

for example:

```
yn = [[1,2,3],[2,3,4], [3,4,5],[4,5,6], ...]
x = [[1,2,3],[2,3,4], [3,4,5],[4,5,6], ...]
labels = ['label1', 'label2', 'label3', ...]
```

and then:

```
fig = plot.figure(figsize=(11.69, 8.27), dpi=100)

for i,y in enumerate(yn):
    #new subplot
    ax=fig.add_subplot(18,1,i+1)
    #plot
    ax.plot(x[i], y, 'bo-')
    #y labels
    ax.set_ylabel(labels[i])
    # grid
    ax.grid(True)
plot.show()
```