# How to put a plot defined in a python function into matplotlib suplots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, subplot

people!
I defined a function that makes a graph from matplotlib similar to this one taken from [How to write a function for barchart in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29364943/how-to-write-a-function-for-barchart-in-python):

```
def df_bar(df, xcol, ycol, xlabel=None, ylabel=None, title=None):
    if xlabel is None:
        xlabel = xcol
    if ylabel is None:
        ylabel = xcol    
    ax = textranges_freq.plot(x=xcol,y=ycol,kind='bar',title=title, width=0.5, legend=False)
    ax.set_xlabel(xlabel)
    ax.set_ylabel(ylabel)
    plt.show()
```

My question is how to plot that into a matplotlib subplots funtion, what I mean is that, I want that graph appears two times side by side each, how do I make this?

I tried to define fig, axs and then using slicing "axs[0]" to plot, but didn't work, not even using subplots on matplotlib figure:

```
"ax1 = plt.subplot(1, 3, 1)
df_bar()
plt.title('bedrooms')"
```

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html

Comment: 1. `fig, (ax1,ax2,ax3) = plt.subplots(1, 3)` 2. add an `ax=None` param to your function 3. add the `ax` to your plot command like `textranges_freq.plot(..., ax=ax)` 4. call `df_bar(..., ax=ax1)` and so on

Comment: Note that this is `plt.subplots` ending in `s`